# Parsing HTML knock-off for answering queries for values

Tags: c++, parsing, c++17

I wrote a code to parse an [HTML knock-off from HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/attribute-parser/problem), and I would like a review. Mostly I hope to get better at STL and code style. But any tips would be very welcome.

Sample input that I would read from `cin` to parse and answer queries:

> 4 3
>   <tag1 value = "HelloWorld">
>   <tag2 name = "Name1">
>   </tag2>
>   </tag1>
>   tag1.tag2~name
>   tag1~name
>   tag1~value

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    std::string scope, cin_buffer, name;
    std::string::iterator strg_it;
    int lines, querrys;
    std::map<std::string,std::string> variables;

    std::cin >> cin_buffer;
    lines = atoi(cin_buffer.c_str());
    std::cin >> cin_buffer;
    querrys = atoi(cin_buffer.c_str());

    for (int lines_processed=0; lines_processed<lines; ++lines_processed){
        std::cin >> std::ws;
        while (std::cin.peek()!= '\n'){
            std::cin >> cin_buffer;
            if (cin_buffer.at(0)=='<' && cin_buffer.at(1)!='/'){
                strg_it = remove_if( begin(cin_buffer), end(cin_buffer), 
                                    [](unsigned char c){return c=='<' || c=='>';});
                cin_buffer.erase(strg_it, end(cin_buffer));
                if (scope.length()>0){
                    scope += "." + cin_buffer;
                }else{
                    scope = cin_buffer;
                } 
            }else if (cin_buffer.at(0)=='<' && cin_buffer.at(1)=='/'){
                int length_to_erase = (scope.length())-(cin_buffer.length()-3);
                scope.erase(length_to_erase);
                if (scope.back()=='.'){
                    scope.erase(scope.length()-1);
                }
            }else{
                name = scope + "~" + cin_buffer; 
                std::cin >> cin_buffer; 
                std::cin >> cin_buffer; 
                strg_it = remove_if( begin(cin_buffer), end(cin_buffer), 
                                    [](unsigned char c){return c=='"' || c=='>';} );
                cin_buffer.erase(strg_it, end(cin_buffer));
                variables[name]=cin_buffer;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int querry_number=0; querry_number<querrys; ++querry_number){
        std::cin >> cin_buffer;
        if (variables.find(cin_buffer)!=end(variables)){
            std::cout << variables[cin_buffer] << std::endl;
        }else{
            std::cout << "Not Found!" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview@SE. I took the liberty to remove the advance thanks in accordance with [Expected Behavior](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). You have done well on [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), another thing to keep in mind would be [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good to see that you've avoided the use of `using namespace std;`.

**Coding**

Declare variables as close to their initial use as possible, and prefer construction of that initial value to default constructing an object then assigning the initial value.  `lines` and `querrys` can be declared when they are assigned:

```
auto lines = atoi(cin_buffer.c_str());
// ...
auto querrys = atoi(cin_buffer.c_str());
```

`name` can be declared where it is used.  `strg_it` can also be declared (in both places) as `auto`.  This can help the compiler improve the code by letting it know the value isn't needed after the `erase` call.

```
auto strg_it = remove_if( begin(cin_buffer), end(cin_buffer), 
                    [](unsigned char c){return c=='<' || c=='>';});
cin_buffer.erase(strg_it, end(cin_buffer));
```

Alternatively, when using the erase-remove idiom, you can put the erase and remove in one statement

```
    cin_buffer.erase(remove_if( begin(cin_buffer), end(cin_buffer), [](unsigned char c){return c=='<' || c=='>';}), end(cin_buffer));
```

and not need the variable at all.

You have no error checking on your inputs.  You should check for failed input, non-integer conversions from `atoi`, etc.  One alternative (since you have a `std::string`) is to use [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), which will throw an exception if there is an error during conversion.

`cin_buffer.at(0)` will throw with an empty string, and `cin_buffer.at(1)` will throw an exception if the string only has one character in it.

`variables[name]=cin_buffer;` will replace any existing value for `name` if one already exists.  This may be the expected behavior.

In your final search loop, store the result of `find` in a variable to avoid having to look it up again.

```
auto it = variables.find(cin_buffer);
if (it != end(variables)) {
    std::cout << it->second << `\n`;
} else
```

You should avoid using `std::endl` unless absolutely necessary.  Since it flushes the output, there can be a considerable performance hit when using it.

**Readability**

You should put more spaces in your code, rather than jamming all those characters together.  Put spaces around binary operators

```
for (int lines_processed = 0; lines_processed < lines; ++lines_processed) {
```

which also makes it clearer that `lines_processed < lines` is an expression and not part of a possible template `lines_processed<lines>`.

The parentheses around `(scope.length())` are unnecessary.

Spelling is important.  Variable names should be spelled correctly to make it easier to read and easier to search for.  `querrys` should be spelled `queries`.